# Disable JavaFX TableColumn

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, tableview

Have a `TableColumn` defined as `TableColumn<Target, String> tableColumnLocation;` and is populated like this:

```
tableColumnLocation.setCellValueFactory(new 
PropertyValueFactory<Target, String>("name"));

tableColumnLocation.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(locationValues));
```

where `locationValues` are set of Strings read from a database.
Am trying to disable the `tableColumnLocation` dropdown in case another checkbox column is unselected. So the issue is how to disable `ComboBoxTableCell`. Any recommendations would be highly appreciated.
Have been able to disable other `TableColumn` as shown below but not sure on how to proceed on this one.

```
tableColumnQty.setCellFactory(
                     new Callback<TableColumn<Test, String>, TableCell<Test, String>>() {

                         @Override
                         public TableCell<Test, String> call(TableColumn<Test, String> paramTableColumn) {
                             return new TextFieldTableCell<Test, String>(new DefaultStringConverter()) {
                                 @Override
                                 public void updateItem(String s, boolean b) {
                                     super.updateItem(s, b);
                                     if(!isEmpty()) {
                                         Test item = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
                                         if (item.getTarget().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                                             setDisable(true);
                                             setEditable(false);
                                             this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgrey");
                                         } else {
                                             setDisable(false);
                                             setEditable(true);
                                             //if(s != null && !s.equalsIgnoreCase(""))

                                             setStyle("");
                                         }
                                     }
                                 }
                             };
                         }

                     });
```

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly

Comment: @kleopatra Have added more details now

Comment: you did read the referenced help page, didn't you? So why don't you provide what's suggested?  Not doing it is an incredible waste of time  for everybody..

Comment: @kleopatra Can you be specific about what you would need. I don't know how to proceed in a specific situation which I have described.

Comment: don't know what your problem is (subclassing the combo cell, deciding when to not edit, how to not edit... any of the other possibilies?), without a mcve there's no way of knowing ...

Comment: @kleopatra I see, the problem is need to know how to not edit or disable ComboBoxTableCell. Updating the above post now

Comment: nothing happened into direction of a mcve - why not? what's so difficult to understand? the referenced help page has a clear-cut description of what you should do and you don't.  Be happy with not doing what is required, I'm off :((

Comment: @kleopatra Will go over it in a bit and provide the needed thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
tableColumnLocation.setCellFactory(
                     new Callback<TableColumn<Target, String>, TableCell<Target, String>>() {

                         @Override
                         public TableCell<Target, String> call(TableColumn<Target, String> paramTableColumn) {
                             return new ComboBoxTableCell<Target, String>(new DefaultStringConverter(), locationValues) {
                                 @Override
                                 public void updateItem(String s, boolean b) {
                                     super.updateItem(s, b);
                                     if(!isEmpty()) {
                                         Target item = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
                                         if (check if checkbox is unselected) {
                                             setDisable(true);
                                             setEditable(false);
                                             this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgrey");
                                         } else {
                                             setDisable(false);
                                             setEditable(true);
                                             setStyle("");
                                         }
                                     }
                                 }
                             };
                         }

                     });
```